# python, open parenthesis at beginning of line inserts a space

Tags: python, indentation

Python code snippet

```
    (imin_f, jmin_f), (imax_f, jmax_f) = island_f
     non_overlap =set()
```

`n` of non_overlab is behind `(` , I can't tell which mode is doing it..

c-h k ( gives.

```
( runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map), which is
an interactive built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(self-insert-command N &optional C)

Insert the character you type.
Whichever character C you type to run this command is inserted.
The numeric prefix argument N says how many times to repeat the insertion.
Before insertion, ‘expand-abbrev’ is executed if the inserted character does
not have word syntax and the previous character in the buffer does.
After insertion, ‘internal-auto-fill’ is called if
‘auto-fill-function’ is non-nil and if the ‘auto-fill-chars’ table has
a non-nil value for the inserted character.  At the end, it runs
‘post-self-insert-hook’.

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 22.1.
```